# Maven build runs when I run a Unit test in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, junit4, m2eclipse

I have a maven project. I am trying to run a single test in maven command line and that works fine. I am trying to debug that test in eclipse and using -Dmaven.surefire.debug option and starting a debug on port 5005 as "Remote Application" in maven - ref http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html

Now when I do so - as part of my maven command in command line all classes/test-classes, spring config get compiled and put in right places. However when I am Run Debug from eclipse when the test pauses to listen on port 5005 - I see eclipse is running a maven build all over again and all classes are recompiled. And while doing this it is not picking up all the profiles required for the test as not all profiles are active by default. I could fix that by Project->Properties->Maven and set the active Maven profiles there.

What I am looking for if why is eclipse trying to do a maven build when I am trying to run my test for which a compiled class is already present? Is that a default behaviour of eclipse maven plugin m2e? And can this be turned off - so that it only executes the class instead of trying a maven build?

Comment: Hi Soumya! Are you using the most up to date version of Eclipse (4.2SR2)? The Maven Eclipse integration is called m2e these days, and has come a long way since m2eclipse.

Comment: Hi Art I am using Eclipse Juno 4.2 and  I am using m2e :) Sorry for the wrong info in the original question - have changed it to m2e in the question now.

Comment: How exactly are you running the test from Eclipse? Right clicking class and Run As -> JUnit?

Comment: Well that is one way and I got that working. And I appreciate that it will do a maven build. My question is more around if I can turn off the maven build part though it is essentially a maven project. If you see the link I posted I am running a test from command prompt and then making it pause for debug and listen on port 5005 and then Start a Remote Application debug on eclipse for the test on port 5005. That is when I don't want eclipse to do the maven build once again as that is already done by the test run from command prompt

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Eclipse Run Configuration that you're using?